# Eclipse JDT SearchEngine for Text search

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to search a string in all java source files from a particular project and list the matches using eclipse JDT. I could find sample code to search for method reference or field level reference and so on. But i just need to search a text or string within the java source. It may be a calling method or may be class name or whatever. Can anyone please help me.

Thanks
Manivannan

Comment: Thanks @tkotisis  for grammatical correction. Can you help me to achieve this?

Comment: just look how eclipse platform implemented search. org.eclipse.search.internal.ui.SearchDialog